# HttpWebRequest BeginGetResponse Action delegate lambda expression as parameter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, functional-programming, lambda

I have this code:

```
   protected static string MakeGetRequest(string url, Action<IAsyncResult> callback)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.BeginGetResponse(callback, null);            
    }
```

This will not compile, I get an error on the BeginGetResponse line:

cannot convert from 'System.Action' to 'System.AsyncCallback'

I want to pass in a function as my AsyncCallback.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an object of type `AsyncCallback`. Try this instead:

```
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(callback), null);
```